# GitHub new token system

Tags: git, authentication, github, token

Recently i received an email from GitHub saying that I have used my user and password to push data for a remote repository

[image: Email from GitHub]

And this will be deprecated soon. I already get the access token for my GitHub account, but where do i store it? I'll need to type it every time that I use `git push`?

Btw, i have the `~/.gitconfig` file, but it's not working (every time that i push data for a remote repository i need to insert my credentials again)

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

- create a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token)
- use that PAT as your password (instead of your current GitHub account password)
- [setup a Git credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache) (`git config credential.helper`) in order to cache those credentials (GitHub username + token), and to not have to enter them on every Git remote operation.